# If constructor of a class requires pointer object of second object, what would be the UML relationship?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, uml

I have two classes `A` and `B`. If constructor of `class A` requires pointer to the object of `class B`,

```
             `A(B* b)`.
```

In this case, what would be the UML relationship between class A and B?

**Edit**

In further detail, I have following situation:

I have three classes `A`, `B` and `C`. Here, `C` inherits from `B`.

`class A` constructor code looks like: `A(B* b)`.

`class C` instantiates a pointer to object of `A` in its constructor with code:
`A* a = new A(this)`.

Destructor of `class C` destroys `pointer a` with code: `delete a`.

Wouldn't this has all composition, dependency and generalization relations as shown in attached figure?

[image]

Comment: If a `DependantPart` requires a `RequiredPart` then it is a Dependency Relationship.

Comment: _@skyaakash_ Note that UML is meant for graphical representation primarily, such you should provide your attempt of a diagram here.

Comment: Your question is incomplete and cannot be answered in a meaningful way. Normally, if a constructor takes a pointer to an object of another class, this constructor parameter corresponds to a class property that references that class and represents an association, as exlplained in the answer of Christophe. Is this the structure you refer to in your question? The answer of @πάντα ῥεῖ is not satisfactory, since a dependency in UML is a very weak kind of relationship without much meaning.

Comment: @gwag A pointer taken at the constructor no way qualifies that the parameter is actually used as a member for that class. It could qualify a builder, or whatever. Unless the question isn't more specific _dependency_ is the way to go.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I have no idea what your "no way" sentence means. Of course, when a class implements an association between `Company` and `Person` with a reference property `Person::employer` of type `Company*`, then you may use a pointer-valued constructor parameter for setting this property on object creation.

Comment: @skyaakash: You still did not explain what you really mean by explaining the intended meanings of your classes and pointers. Better don't use an abstract example.

Comment: @gwag It meanns that you cannot conclude from the constructor parameter that the pointer will be actually used as member of that class.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I didn't conclude this, I just said "normally" this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward relationship is a *Dependency* (indicated by the dashed directed connector line):

[image]

You may adorn that with more specific stereotypes like e.g. «use»:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Of course, if the pointer to B has to be provided at construction, there is without a discussion a dependency, as [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96) pointed out.

However pointers in classes are a way to implement a navigable association between classes.  So if the pointer is kept by A (e.g. as a member) it would be more than a simple dependency; it would be an association between the classes (plain line between A and B):

- if the pointer can be `nullptr` it's an optional association with a multiplicity 0..1, if not it would be a mandatory association 1
- if the pointer would be added to a container member to which other pointers could be added as well, it would be a one to many association (multiplicity 0..n or a 1..n depending if `nullptr` is allowed at construction or not)
- as the pointer would allow you to navigate from A to B (but not necessarily from B to A), you can show this association as navigable with an arrow:

  [image]